# text field auto-complete - only allow submissions within autocomplete options

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am looking for code that allows an autocomplete, only within a specified data array.  So only data within the auto complete array is allowed to be entered.  Not sure where to start looking.

Thanks!

Comment: How about you try first then we help you get some efficient working code? Google is your friend :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution, which utilises [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), should suffice - of course it might need some further tweaking depending on your *specific* requirements.

Markup:

```
<input id="autocomplete"/>
<br />
<input id="submit" type="submit" disabled="disabled"/>
```

Script:

```
var source = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'];

$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: source,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
}).keyup(function() {
    var $parentContext = $(this);
    var matches = $.grep(source, function(n, i) {
        return $parentContext.val().toLowerCase() == n.toLowerCase();
    });
    $("#submit").attr("disabled", !matches.length);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/Ezbns/

Further reading:

- http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/

Comment: This may work, but DON'T DON'T DON'T rely on Javascript for validation. Javascript is easily bypassed and a hacker could easily submit malicious/invalid information if this is your only validation. You MUST implement server-side validation.

Comment: @Seth - I never suggested that this is a substitute for server-side validation. I just rigged up a little client-side script to do what he asked - but good that you pointed that out, as I clearly failed to do so.

Comment: apologies - i wasn't saying your answer was wrong. I'm sorry. I just wanted to make sure that @user was aware that this is NOT a full solution. I didn't want to post an answer because it would get down-voted :(

Comment: @seth.vargo - Relax, you've nothing to apologise for :)