# How to restrict users to enter text other than Autocomplete text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created an add/remove dynamic fields with Autocomplete function. I want user to restrict users to enter text other than Autocomplete text. Following is my code...

```js
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        
        var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper         = $("#username-fields"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button      = $("#add-username-fields"); //Add button ID
        
        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        var availableAttributes = [
   "account_address",
   "account_address_city",
   "account_address_country",
   "account_address_state"
    ];
        
        $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $(wrapper).append('<div class="fund-fields"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_login[]" placeholder=""></div></div><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_role[]" placeholder=""></div></div><div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="remove-username-fields"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove</button></div></div></div>'); 
                
                $(wrapper).find("input[name^='user_login']").autocomplete({
                    source: availableAttributes
                }); 
                //add input box
            }
        });
        
        $(wrapper).on("click","#remove-username-fields", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
        
        $("input[name^='user_login']").autocomplete({
      source: availableAttributes
     });
     
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id="add-username-fields">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="user_login[]"></div>
    
    <div id="username-fields">
    
    </div>
```

Plz help me out... Thanks...

Comment: Your question is a little unclear - Are you only wanting the form to accept certain text, or the completed form to submit certain text?

Comment: seem to be identical https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550766/text-field-auto-complete-only-allow-submissions-within-autocomplete-options

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve] with relevant libraries

Comment: @Adam I only want the user to be allowed to select from the list of items that are presented in the autocomplete list, and dont want them to be able to write some random text.

Comment: @Minesh I think what you really want is a selectmenu that is filtered with keypad input.  it is a blurry line.  ultimately though you will need to do a server-side check, best by ajax, and return success or fail to the client.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) you can use the `change` event to check whether the user has selected any item from the list. Your autocomplete code will look like this.

```
$(wrapper).find("input[name^='user_login']").autocomplete({
   source: availableAttributes,
   change: function( event, ui ) {
      if (ui.item == null) {
         $(this).val("");
         $(this).focus();
      }
   }
});
```

**EDIT:** 
The complete js code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper         = $("#username-fields"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button      = $("#add-username-fields"); //Add button ID

        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        var availableAttributes = [
           "account_address",
           "account_address_city",
           "account_address_country",
           "account_address_state"
         ];

        $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $(wrapper).append('<div class="fund-fields"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_login[]" placeholder=""></div></div><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_role[]" placeholder=""></div></div><div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="remove-username-fields"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove</button></div></div></div>'); 

                $(wrapper).find("input[name^='user_login']").autocomplete({
                    source: availableAttributes,
                    change: function( event, ui ) { // <---- here
                       if (ui.item == null) {
                         $(this).val("");
                         $(this).focus();
                       }
                     }
                }); 
                //add input box
            }
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click","#remove-username-fields", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })

        $("input[name^='user_login']").autocomplete({
            source: availableAttributes,
            change: function( event, ui ) { // <---- and here
               if (ui.item == null) {
                   $(this).val("");
                   $(this).focus();
               }
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: @Minesh Append  `change: function( event, ui ) {
      if (ui.item == null) {
         $(this).val("");
         $(this).focus();
      }
   }` to your `$(wrapper).find("input[name^='user_login']").autocomplete({
                    source: availableAttributes
                });` So your code would look like my answer. It worked when I tried.